# How to prevent a user from hiding their bash history?

Tags: linux, bash

I believe that there are a large number of ways to prevent your bash history being recorded e.g. export HISTSIZE=0, how can I prevent users from hiding their bash history?

Comment: Replace `bash` with your own changes. Without doing that, you _can not_ prevent people from hiding their history. Of course, if you do that and don't tell them, well there are other issues. The better approach is if you don't trust your users, don't allow them on the system.

Comment: Can't you prevent the export of HISTSIZE=0?

Comment: You cannot prevent the user from changing an environment variable. You can set the initial value but the user can change it with no effort.

Comment: I tried on my system and it didn't change though.. is there another way then than that example?

Comment: Bash history is a security hole. As a user, I'd question the administrator's intentions and the sweet deal where he leaves the system open to compromise because passwords are not removable from the history.

Comment: `kill -9 $$` will _always_ prevent `.bash_history` from being written, and you can't stop a user from executing it. So, you can't do it 100%.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

make it `readonly HISTSIZE` in your `/etc/profile`

Comment: You cannot prevent the user from changing an environment variable.

Comment: you can't prevent *some* users from changing environment variables...

Comment: Isn't _some_ enough to be going through a fruitless exercise on this subject though? It's like inventing copy protection that only _some_ people are able to subvert.

Comment: `$  bash --noprofile`? (note: space before the command)

Comment: -1. There are a variety of ways for anyone who can read the `bash` man page to get around this.

Comment: anyone who can use google can get around anything

Answer (score 4):

#### Use the Append-Only Attribute

You could use root to modify the attributes of the .bash_history file, but this will cause problems when Bash tries to truncate the file to HISTSIZE or otherwise overwrite the file. For example:

```
sudo chattr +a ~username/.bash_history
```

With this flag in place, even root can't delete or truncate the file without first remove the append-only flag.

Answer (score 1):

A user can always do "HISTFILE=/some/innocuous/place" which will leave the default history file intact. Thus append-only on the default file will only prevent users from reducing the file, but it does not force users to save their history to the default.

Answer (score 1):

I use `chattr +a .bash_history`, which prevents users from deleting the history file.

Of course, users will still be able to change the HIST... variables, but this will show up in the .bash_history. You will be able to check if they were doing things like using a different HISTFILE to cover their tracks.